# What is the correct way to count number of nodes using Cypher?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

For both of these queries, I get the same result.

Query 1:

```
MATCH (e:Episode)
RETURN COUNT(e);
```

Query 2:

```
MATCH (e:Episode)
WITH COUNT(e) AS count
RETURN count;
```

What would be the correct way to count the number of nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no functional difference for such a simple query. Go with the first option, it is shorter and expresses very clearly what you want.

If you run both your queries with `EXPLAIN` or `PROFILE`, you will see that the executions plans are identical.

Comment: And what is better coding practice? I guess to keep it as shot as possible.